# node container keeps failing to install dependencies websocket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, drone.io

I'm trying to build my test container using drone ci but it always fails
when trying to install websocket.io

with the error, I added `npm install -g node-gyp` as adviced but the problem still exists

```
npm info lifecycle compression@1.6.2~install: compression@1.6.2
npm info lifecycle express@4.14.0~install: express@4.14.0
npm info lifecycle nodeadmin@0.1.2~install: nodeadmin@0.1.2
npm info lifecycle vizion@0.2.13~install: vizion@0.2.13
npm info lifecycle websocket@1.0.24~install: websocket@1.0.24\
websocket@1.0.24 install /drone/src/bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxxxxxx/node_modules/websocket
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
make: Entering directory '/drone/src/bitbucket.org/xxxxxx/xxxx/node_modules/websocket/build'
 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "calm-cell",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "th backend app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "setup":"./node_modules/.bin/mocha 'test/setupDb.js' --reporter spec  --timeout 3000",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha 'test/appTest.js' --reporter spec  --timeout 3000",
    "test:client": "karma start --single-run",
    "test:server": "mocha --recursive"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "^0.0.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "bookshelf": "^0.9.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-validator": "^2.20.4",
    "json-2-csv": "^2.0.22",
    "json2csv": "^3.6.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "jwt-then": "^0.4.1",
    "knex": "^0.10.0",
    "loadtest": "^1.4.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "nodeadmin": "^0.1.2",
    "nodemailer": "^2.5.0",
    "opbeat": "^3.16.0",
    "pdf-invoice": "^1.0.2",
    "pm2": "^1.1.3",
    "pmx": "^0.6.3",
    "request": "^2.69.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.0.1",
    "mocha": "^2.5.3",
    "nodeman": "^1.1.2",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.12.1",
    "sinon": "^1.17.3",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "supertest": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.1.0"
  }
}
```

and this is drone yml file

```
build:
  image: node:boron
  commands:
    - npm install -g node-gyp
    - npm update # Update your personal npm local repository again.
    - npm  install 
    - npm run setup
    - npm run test
  environment:
    - EXAM_SERVER_URL=http://S8.dummy.com
    - FETCH_SERVER_FETCH_API='/getSomething?something='
    - TOKEN_SECRET=superSecretFakeToken
    - DB_HOST=localhost
    - DB_USER=root
    - DB_PASSWORD=thisIsFakePassword
    - DB_NAME=thisIsFakeDB

  compose:
    database:
      image: mysql:5.6
      environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=thisIsFakePassword
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=thisIsFakeDB
```

Comment: is it possible the `node:boron` image you are using has a version of node incompatible with node-gyp? I google the error message and it brought me to this thread on GitHub, which indicates older versions of node are incompatible https://github.com/websockets/bufferutil/issues/22

Comment: also, I'm not sure drone is relevant to this issue. You get the same error by running these commands directly in your docker client. `docker run -t -i node:boron /bin/sh -c "npm install -g node-gyp && npm install websocket@1.0.24"`

Comment: I tried <code>  image: node:7.4.0 </code> at websocket didn't break it thanks